# I'm having an error while "gem uninstall rails"

Tags: bash, rubygems, uninstallation

I want to uninstall rails older version.

While I tried the code `gem uninstall rails`

```
Select gem to uninstall:
1. rails-2.3.4
2. rails-3.2.1
3. rails-3.2.11
4. rails-4.1.6
5. rails-4.1.7
6. rails-4.1.8
7. All versions
> 1
Remove executables:
    rails

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  y
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin directory.
```

If I tried with `sudo`, it shows

```
Select gem to uninstall:
1. rails-4.1.6
2. rails-4.1.8
3. All versions
>
```

There is no sign of other Rails version while trying with sudo.

My current rails version

```
rails -v
Rails 2.3.4
```

I would like to get some assistance to uninstall the other Rails version except 4.1.6.

Thank You In Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change permissions for yourself:

```
$ sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/ -R
```

then try removing rails again:

```
$ gem uninstall rails
```

Answer (score 2):

I have cleared this conflict by running serious of commands using "rvm".

```
rvm repair
rvm cleanup
rvm implode
```

But this commands uninstalled all the rails versions.